# Mysql alter multiple tables together

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I am having around 65 tables in my DB.
Now i want to add foreign key constraint to all the tables, is there any way i can alter multiple tables at same time for same foreign key to be added to all the required tables.

Comment: "add foreign key constraint to all the tables" Why ?

Comment: its not all tables but add foreign key to tables which have connected to their respective parent tables..

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a SP.

Store these 65 tables in a table variable and definition of table variable should be

Declare @table table(ID int IDENTITY (1,1),TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(1000))

now run a loop and till MAX(ID) and run this Alter statement.

As the same foreign key to be added it won't be an issue.

Regards

Ashutosh

Comment: i didn't got your answer